# Gnome Software shows error even though everything is fine

Tags: gnome, archlinux, gnome-3, gnome-shell

When refreshing updates tab I get either
[core]: Unexpected system error
[core]: invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature)

I am using Arch Linux with Gnome 3.18. here is my pacman config

```
#
# /etc/pacman.conf
#
# See the pacman.conf(5) manpage for option and repository directives

#
# GENERAL OPTIONS
#
[options]
# The following paths are commented out with their default values listed.
# If you wish to use different paths, uncomment and update the paths.
#RootDir     = /
#DBPath      = /var/lib/pacman/
#CacheDir    = /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
#LogFile     = /var/log/pacman.log
#GPGDir      = /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
HoldPkg     = pacman glibc
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/curl -C - -f %u > %o
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u
#CleanMethod = KeepInstalled
#UseDelta    = 0.7
Architecture = auto

# Pacman won't upgrade packages listed in IgnorePkg and members of IgnoreGroup
#IgnorePkg   =
#IgnoreGroup =

#NoUpgrade   =
#NoExtract   =

# Misc options
#UseSyslog
#Color
#TotalDownload
CheckSpace
#VerbosePkgLists

# By default, pacman accepts packages signed by keys that its local keyring
# trusts (see pacman-key and its man page), as well as unsigned packages.
SigLevel    = Required DatabaseOptional
LocalFileSigLevel = Optional
#RemoteFileSigLevel = Required

# NOTE: You must run `pacman-key --init` before first using pacman; the local
# keyring can then be populated with the keys of all official Arch Linux
# packagers with `pacman-key --populate archlinux`.

#
# REPOSITORIES
#   - can be defined here or included from another file
#   - pacman will search repositories in the order defined here
#   - local/custom mirrors can be added here or in separate files
#   - repositories listed first will take precedence when packages
#     have identical names, regardless of version number
#   - URLs will have $repo replaced by the name of the current repo
#   - URLs will have $arch replaced by the name of the architecture
#
# Repository entries are of the format:
#       [repo-name]
#       Server = ServerName
#       Include = IncludePath
#
# The header [repo-name] is crucial - it must be present and
# uncommented to enable the repo.
#

# The testing repositories are disabled by default. To enable, uncomment the
# repo name header and Include lines. You can add preferred servers immediately
# after the header, and they will be used before the default mirrors.

#[testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[core]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[extra]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

#[community-testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[community]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

# If you want to run 32 bit applications on your x86_64 system,
# enable the multilib repositories as required here.

#[multilib-testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[multilib]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

# An example of a custom package repository.  See the pacman manpage for
# tips on creating your own repositories.
#[custom]
#SigLevel = Optional TrustAll
#Server = file:///home/custompkgs

[archlinuxfr]
SigLevel = Never
Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch

[infinality-bundle]
SigLevel = Never
Server = http://bohoomil.com/repo/$arch

[infinality-bundle-multilib]
SigLevel = Never
Server = http://bohoomil.com/repo/multilib/$arch

[infinality-bundle-fonts]
SigLevel = Never
Server = http://bohoomil.com/repo/fonts
```

And when updating with pacman there are no issues.

[image: Gnome Software error updating while terminal is fine]

I have no issues to use terminal, I just want to know what is the problem with gnome software and is it a false positive error or there is some issues indeed with my repos?

Comment: As a general troubleshooting recommendation, I would suggest that you temporarily remove your custom repositories / unsupported packages, reboot, and then try to use the update functionality of Gnome Software again.

What unsupported packages do you have currently installed on your system? `$ pacman -Qm` will give you a list.

Comment: Tried commenting out/removing custom repos from the pacman.conf file, nothing helped. Eventually I ran into another, major issue this time, and had to do a clean arch install and since then Gnome Software did not report any errors.

Comment: Interesting... I just resolved this same issue for myself and the culprit turned out to be my unsupported `gnome-defaults-list` package. Did you happen to install that AUR package at any point in time?

Comment: Nope, never had that one, at least not to my knowledge. I will remember that package name in case issues arise again.